# Ubuntu 21.10 - My battery icon doesn't show my battery charging when plugged in

Tags: laptop, battery, thinkpad, 21.10, charging

When my battery is low, I'll plug in my charger and hear the sound it makes to let me know it's charging, but the icon still shows a red low battery icon. I can get the icon to show it's charging by closing the lid on my laptop and making it reopening it after sleeping.

Comment: I've got a related issue with my battery icon not showing plugged in status. Ubuntu 22.04, MSI Bravo 15 AMD Ryzen 7 laptop.